# Implementation for {"mdm":"<PushMagic>"} using javapns

Tags: apple-push-notifications, mdm

I am using javapns to develop apple push notification mdm server. There is a package  "javapns.notification.management"  I could not find an api to send {"mdm":""} to apple.

I want to implement MDM solution using javapns. I have installed the mobileConfig  and have the deviceToken and pushMagic String. Next I want to send {"mdm":""} and then the other commands.

Is this possible using javapns and if yes - is there a sample or some inputs of how to do it?

Issue #37 in javapns says it is possible to send mdm payloads but I could not figure how.

I really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the javapns implementation, but I have implemented 2 solutions using the java-apns library (https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns) that send across the MDM payload.

Comment: did you send "mdm:" payload or just regular payload with "aps:" prefix?

Comment: it's an MDM server, so the "mdm:" payload

Answer (score 0):

As Abstractec mentioned you can use notnoop library. It works for MDM push notifications.